# C# RegEx to match a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

For a programming question I need to change every last letter of every word to uppercase. Egs: `This is a string` should be changed to `ThiS iS A strinG`. I have very little prior knowledge of Regular Expressions and this is what I could come up with (here s is variable name for my string):

```
return Regex.Replace(s,@"(?:\w\s|\s\a)",c=>c.Value.ToUpper());
```

The problem with this expression is that it is not converting last alphabet of string (i.e 'G' in 'strinG'). Any help is appreciated. Thanks

BTW there are two more method that I am able to come up with for this problem but as you see they are way too clumsy and I want the solution to be neater.
1.

```
return new String(s.Select((x,i)=>(i+1==s.Length ||s[i+1]==' ')?Char.ToUpper(x):x).ToArray());
```

2.

```
return new String(((new CultureInfo("en-US",false)).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(new String(s.Reverse().ToArray()))).Reverse().ToArray());
```

Comment: The main reason those other solutions look "clumsy" and not "neat" is becasuse you're doing them all on one line!

Comment: I like your last option.  However, if you're convinced you need to go down the regex road, you should look into "word boundaries". http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: No, @BenAaronson, regexes really are the solution here.

Comment: @jwg I don't disagree. They'd be my first choice given the simplicity of the regex required in this case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of

```
?:\w\s|\s\a
```

Use

```
?:\w\b|\s\a
```

Which looks for a character immediately before a word boundary rather than whitespace.

## EDIT

As pointed out by the OP this also needed `\b` before the bell character too, thus:

```
?:\w\b|\b\a
```

[RegExr example](http://regexr.com/38sfm)

Comment: Second part needed to be changed. I changed it to ?:\w\s|\w\b and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah just been reading up on that bit as I've not used the bell character before myself, but just tried it out on RegExr and found out what it is and that it needed changing. Will add an edit to my post for completeness.

Comment: `\b` **does not mean** 'the bell character'! -1 for answering this question, seemingly without understanding how regexes work, or what the OP was trying to do with them.

Comment: @jwg - I didn't say it was. I said `\b` was the word boundary and correctly stated that `\a` is a bell character. I suggest you read things more carefully before chucking about insults.

Comment: Why do you think the OP's original regex is correct (except for the last char in a string)?

Comment: @jwg - What's your point? At no time did I claim `\b` to be a bell character. The regex clearly wouldn't work because to the lack of a preceding white space before the last character. Having not used `\a` myself before, having never found a need for it in 15 years) I omitted this by mistake in the first part of the answer. In the edit I changed this as per the OP's comment. In fact in the example given by the OP the regex could just be `(?:\w\b)`, there is no need for the `or` part at all. And you still haven't managed to justify your accusation.

Comment: My point is that the original regex was nonsense. Rather than identifying this or suggesting something sensible, you corrected it to some slightly different nonsense. You are still suggesting nonsense - with the unnecessary `?:` and parens. This makes your answer a bad answer, in contrast to the other answer.

Comment: @jwg - So what? I rushed it and overlooked something but my answer was accepted anyway. Yes, the other suggestion works and yes, it is better. Big deal - happens all the time. By all means comment and explain that but simply slagging people off with baseless accusations is not the way to go about it. Why did you not post an answer yourself if you're that bothered? This is a pointless discussion. Move on.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
return Regex.Replace(s, @"(\w)\b", c => c.Value.ToUpper());
```